# How to get data attribute inside each loop?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building a form with HTML and jQuery and need to concatenate various input fields for the Ajax request.

The form looks like this:

```html
<div class="row">
From: <input data-name="formField" data-input="from">
To: <input data-name="formField" data-input="to">
Price: <input data-name="formField" data-input="price">
</div>
<div class="row">
<br>
From: <input data-name="formField" data-input="from">
To: <input data-name="formField" data-input="to">
Price: <input data-name="formField" data-input="price">
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
From: <input data-name="formField" data-input="from">
To: <input data-name="formField" data-input="to">
Price: <input data-name="formField" data-input="price">
</div>
<br>
Result:<input id="result">
```

The result I need is this:

```
[{from=1, to=5, value=50}, {from=6, to=10, value=60}, {from=11, to=15, value=70}]
```

This is what I tried with jQuery:

```
$("input[data-name=formField]").change(function() {
    var rows = $('.row');
    var result = [];
    $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
        $.each(row, function(i, field) {
            rowData = {};
            rowData[field.attr("data-input")] = field.val();
        })
        result.push(rowData);
    })
    $('#result').val(result);
})
```

I tried this but I get `field.attr is not a function`. How can I target elements inside each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once inside the loop of rows, you need to use .find() on the formfields;

```
var formFields = $(row).find("input[data-name='formField']");
```

Then use `rowData[$(field).attr("data-input")] = $(field).val();` to assign to a specific property, we wrapped `field` with `$()`.

Lastly, use `JSON.stringify(result)`.

See the demo below.

```js
$("input[data-name=formField]").change(function() {
  var rows = $('.row');
  var result = [];
  var rowData = {};
  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    rowData={};
    var formFields = $(row).find("input[data-name='formField']");
    $.each(formFields, function(i, field) {
      rowData[$(field).attr("data-input")] = $(field).val();
    });
    result.push(rowData);
    
  })
  $('#result').val(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  From: <input data-name="formField" data-input="from"> To: <input data-name="formField" data-input="to"> Price: <input data-name="formField" data-input="price">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <br> From: <input data-name="formField" data-input="from"> To: <input data-name="formField" data-input="to"> Price: <input data-name="formField" data-input="price">
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
  From: <input data-name="formField" data-input="from"> To: <input data-name="formField" data-input="to"> Price: <input data-name="formField" data-input="price">
</div>
<br> Result:
<textarea id="result" style="width:300px; height:300px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: I thought this would work but it only takes the last input row. I don't understand why.

Comment: `  var rowData = {};` should be inside the first loop.

Comment: @TomBomb thanks mate, I edited it with your correction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the field again

```
$("input[data-name=formField]").change(function() {
var rows = $('.row');
var result = [];
var f;
$.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $.each(row, function(i, field) {
        f = $(field);
        rowData = {};
        rowData[f.attr("data-input")] = f.val();
    })
    result.push(rowData);
})
$('#result').val(result);
})
```